# Forward Firebird database to another network

Tags: database, networking, firebird

Ive got a problem by connecting two shop applications with one database. The problem is they are in two different Networks...

Lets say we have **network A**:

```
192.168.1.10 = Master Instance -> uses fdb -> localhost:3065
192.168.1.20 = Other Instance  -> uses fdb -> 192.168.1.10:3065
```

Now i've got a secound **newtwork B**:

```
192.168.1.5  = Other Instance  -> uses fdb -> 192.168.1.10:3065
```

So the problem is i cant configure an instance to use an external ip, it can only use the internal range.

Is there a way how i can forward the Master Instance to Network B?

I've tried with Hamachi but its extremely unstable..

Thanks for your Help Guys :)

Comment: Firebird has a little used feature to forward to another Firebird instance (it is disabled by default), but it would require at least one machine in network B that is able to talk to the server in network A. Also it is not entirely secure AFAIK.

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Is the Database server accessible from both networks? what's your network mask, as the address you use in your example looks like them are in the same network.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Ping them from Each other.... If that works then the problem is with Firebird instance (it is disabled by default), right now I can assume that you are in the same network at all.. and you will ping all of the networks very smoothly so the problem will be with fire-bird.. or in 2nd case tell me the Sub-net Mask... or write your I.P with Network Bits like "192.168.1.10/24...25....26" Then i can tell you what is the issue.... 
Hope this explains